# i Can't consume Create Envelope method

Tags: docusignapi

Some days ago I developed an integration with DocuSign, and then I got my token with RequestJWTUserToken and sent some emails with my code.
From today on, I can't send emails anymore, I also tried making a new request to get a new token, but when I call CreateEnvelope method, I get this error:

```
{"errorCode":"USER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED",
 "message":"One or both of Username and Password are invalid. Invalid access token"}
```

It looks like my token doesn't have permission

[image: Email received in friday]

[image: my code]

Comment: Your question must be self-sufficient as much as possible (code in the question as text), with proper english, code formatted as code, etc. Review your title too for the case.

Answer (score 0):

Your token may have expired.
The access token must be bound to the user's session.
The expires_in parameter shows the remaining lifetime of the token.

Read the section: Use refresh tokens

[https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/authcode/authcode-get-token/#:~:text=If%20you%20have%20obtained%20the,30%20days%20from%20first%20login](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/authcode/authcode-get-token/#:%7E:text=If%20you%20have%20obtained%20the,30%20days%20from%20first%20login)).

Comment: thanks for the reply iamzepp, but I actually don't receive any refresh token when I call RequestJWTUserToken, what i'm receiving as a response in the refresh token API  is "{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"token_type_mismatch"}"

Answer (score 0):

I solved it for now, by doing this:
After authenticating, I used the method "GetUserInfo", grabbed it's BaseUri, and as I instantiate my ApiClient, I used that URL, on addition of "/restapi" and now I am able to create envelopes again